# Class inheritance, super()

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-2.7

I'm just starting to get the hang of classes so I thought I'd try to practice it making a simple population-dynamics program. I don't quite understand how to implement super(). I was reading some old posts and other online forum stuff, but I can't get anything to work. Can someone explain to me why?

```
class Females(object):
    '''Female population settings. Defines the pregnancy rates, death rates,
     and live births for a year.'''

    def __init__(self,female):
        super(Females,self).__init__()
        self.female = female
        self.live_birth

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Current female population: {0}'.format(str(self.female))

    def death(self):
        self.female_death_oldage=int((randint(0,50)*0.01)*female)
        return self.female_death_oldage

    def pregnancies(self):
        self.female_pregnancies=int(((randint(0,100)*0.01)*female)*0.2)
        return self.female_pregnancies

    def live_birth(self):
        self.live_births=int(self.female_pregnancies*((randint(0,100)*0.01)))             
        return self.live_births

    def total_females(self):
        self.next_female_generation = female - self.female_death_oldage


class Babies(Females):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Babies,self).__init__()

    def babies_born(self):
        self.little_girls = int(self.live_births*(randint(0,100)*0.01))
        self.little_boys = (self.live_births - self.little_girls)    
        return self.little_boys,self.little_girls

if __name__=='__main__':
    x=Males(male)
    y=Females(female)
    b=Babies()
    print '%r males died from old age' % x.death()
    print '%r females became pregnant' % y.pregnancies()    
    print 'There were %r live births'  % y.live_births()
    print b.babies_born()
```

When I try to run it (using Eclipse Juno), I get this:

```
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Coding/Population/Population.py", line 78, in <module>
    b=Babies()
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Coding/Population/Population.py", line 56, in __init__
    super(Babies,self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

`super` is used to call the base classes of a class.

`Babies` base class is `Females`, as `Females` class constructor expects two arguments you need to pass it two arguments.

```
super(Babies, self).__init__('Mary')
```

This is equivalent to:

```
Females.__init__(self, 'Mary')
```

But super is preferred as you don't need to mention the name of super class explicitly.

Comment: I'm confused about how to call the `live_births` method from the `Females` class into the `Babies` class. Do I even need a super() in the `Babies` class?

Comment: @Matt You mean how to call a method of a superclass that was *not* reimplemented by the subclass? You simply do `subclass_instance.the_method()`.

Comment: @Matt To call the `live_births` method from a Babies's instance there's no need to use `super`, simply call it from a Babies's instance. `super` is required when you need to call a base class's method that was overridden in the child class.

Answer (score 1):

The superclass of Babies is Female, and its init expects two parameters: self and female.

`super(Babies,self).__init__()` calls it with only only one parameter, the implicite `self` missing the second argument.